# Assign Python method generic argument to class generic argument by default

Tags: python, python-typing

Say I want a method to return a generic type and I would like it to default to the a argument of *the class* by default but to still be overridable at function call, like this:

```py
T = TypeVar('T', bound=str)
U = TypeVar('U')

class Foo(Generic[T]):
    def bar(self, response_type: Type[U] = T) -> U:
        pass
```

So you could have:

```py
x: Foo[int] = ...
x.bar() # Returns int
x.bar(response_type=str) # Returns str
```

Does any Python type checker type system support this?

Additionally, I would also like `Foo` to default to `str`, so that:

```py
x = Foo(...)
x.bar() # Returns str by default even if unspecified when constructing Foo
```

Does the `bound` parameter enable this?

Comment: I answered your first question below. The type variable default is a separate question. And the answer to that is no. Not until [PEP 696](https://peps.python.org/pep-0696/) lands.

Answer (score 1):

Purely from a typing perspective, it is possible to express what you want using [`overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload)s like this:

```py
from typing import Generic, Optional, TypeVar, overload


T = TypeVar("T")
U = TypeVar("U")


class Foo(Generic[T]):
    @overload
    def bar(self, response_type: type[U]) -> U: ...

    @overload
    def bar(self, response_type: None = None) -> T: ...

    def bar(self, response_type: Optional[type] = None) -> object:
        ...  # implementation


x: Foo[int]
reveal_type(x.bar())                   # note: Revealed type is "builtins.int"
reveal_type(x.bar(response_type=str))  # note: Revealed type is "builtins.str"
```

Using `reveal_type` with Mypy shows that the type checker correctly infers the return types this way.

---

The real challenge here could be the actual implementation because without some serious overhead you will not be able to get that type argument passed to `Foo`, unless you pass it in *explicitly* via the constructor for example.

It would be easy of course, if you had it as a mandatory `__init__` argument. Then you could do something like the following:

```py
from typing import Generic, Optional, TypeVar, overload


T = TypeVar("T")
U = TypeVar("U")


class Foo(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, type_arg: type[T]) -> None:
        self.type_arg = type_arg

    @overload
    def bar(self, response_type: type[U]) -> U: ...

    @overload
    def bar(self, response_type: None = None) -> T: ...

    def bar(self, response_type: Optional[type] = None) -> object:
        if response_type is None:
            ...
            return self.type_arg()
        ...
        return response_type()


x = Foo(int)
i = x.bar()
s = x.bar(response_type=str)

print(repr(i))  # 0
print(repr(s))  # ''
```

Obviously the details depend on your actual use case, but you can see the concept.

---

But if you want to rely on passing the type argument via [`__class_getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__class_getitem__) only, you will need to get creative. There is no built-in way to have the default for a method parameter automatically be the type argument passed to `__class_getitem__`.

The way [generic alias types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#generic-alias-type) are constructed, the type argument is completely lost during initialization, meaning when you initialize `Foo[int]` it looks the same as if you were initializing any other `Foo[T]` or just `Foo` for that matter. From the docs:

> parameterized generics erase type parameters during object creation

Now *after* initialization, the `__orig_class__` attribute is added, which points to the generic alias type that was used, but this does not help you in the `__init__` method.

I guess you could defer checking for `__orig_class__` until you call that specific `bar` method in question. So one possible way around this issue could look something like this:

```py
from typing import Generic, Optional, TypeVar, get_args, overload


T = TypeVar("T")
U = TypeVar("U")


class Foo(Generic[T]):
    @overload
    def bar(self, response_type: type[U]) -> U: ...

    @overload
    def bar(self, response_type: None = None) -> T: ...

    def bar(self, response_type: Optional[type] = None) -> object:
        if response_type is not None:
            ...
            return response_type()
        orig_class = getattr(self, "__orig_class__", None)
        if orig_class is None:
            raise TypeError("No type parameter available!")
        type_arg = get_args(orig_class)[0]
        ...
        return type_arg()


x = Foo[int]()
i = x.bar()
s = x.bar(response_type=str)

print(repr(i))  # 0
print(repr(s))  # ''
```

But as pointed out in the comments by @user2357112, this is not a very robust way of doing it. It does not address subclassing, i.e. `class Bar(Foo[int]): ...` will not retain `__orig_class__`. You could again work around that and grab the `__orig_bases__` for example in `__init_subclass__`, but this will get more and more hacky.

In general, you should remember that many typing constructs have minimal or no runtime implications by design. So trying to work *from* typing *to* runtime is always going to be an uphill battle.

Comment: Passing it to init is the way

Comment: Plus, if you rely on the class's type parameter, you run into problems like `x: Foo[int] = Foo(); x.bar()` passing mypy but failing at runtime, or instances of `class Bar(Foo[int]): pass` not having the `__orig_class__` that `Foo.bar` needs.

Comment: @user2357112 You are absolutely right. That last workaround should be considered a fairly fragile hack.